# Windows 7 x64 repeatedly crashing due to high speed torrent download through uTorrent

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, crash, bittorrent, utorrent

My windows 7 x64 keeps on crashing when downloading some torrent which attains high speed. I've installed a software called `WhoCrashed` and tried to analyze the problem. I'm out of my wits as to why this is happening. I've the most update hardware driver installed. Please help.

**Crash dump analysis:**

```
On Thu 10-10-2013 16:05:28 GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\101013-33259-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: netio.sys (0xFFFFF88001D826FD) 
Bugcheck code: 0xD1 (0x28, 0x2, 0x0, 0xFFFFF88001D826FD)
Error: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\netio.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Network I/O Subsystem
Bug check description: This indicates that a kernel-mode driver attempted to access pageable memory at a process IRQL that was too high.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.
```

I'm sharing my crash dump and system information via the following links.

- [Crash Dump](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0Zs6QeILwilLWFMMi1JcEZKSkE/edit?usp=sharing)
- [System Information](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0Zs6QeILwilM3pleWFXamg1WGM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does this happen in any other cases (such as a speedtest)? What is your current computer setup?

Comment: zip and upload the dmp file (dropbox, skydrive) and post the link here.

Comment: This may be due to uPnP. Disable that and see if the problem continues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've shared the link to the crash dump. Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I've added the links for both crash dump and system info. And no it does not happen when doing speed test.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the Realtek 10/100 NIC Family NDIS x64 Driver.

```
0xfffff880035edbb8 : 0xfffff88001d86872 : NETIO!NetioDereferenceNetBufferListChain+0x132
0xfffff880035edc18 : 0xfffff88001e6075a : tcpip!TcpMatchReceive+0x1fa
0xfffff880035edc28 : 0xfffff88001e59634 : tcpip!IppReceiveHeadersHelper+0x454
0xfffff880035edc98 : 0xfffff80002abb401 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x151
0xfffff880035edca0 : 0xfffff88001f69800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\Rtnic64.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for Rtnic64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Rtnic64.sys
0xfffff880035edd68 : 0xfffff88001e61cfb : tcpip!TcpPreValidatedReceive+0x36b
0xfffff880035edda8 : 0xfffff88001e6611a : tcpip!TcpValidateReceive+0x1ba
0xfffff880035eddf8 : 0xfffff88001f69800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
```

Your driver is from 2008:

```
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\Rtnic64.sys
Image name: Rtnic64.sys
Timestamp:        Mon Mar 31 07:39:38 2008
version: 6.108.331.2008
```

Get the [latest driver from Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=6&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Comment: Where can I find the x67 driver for windows 7? I googled it but couldn't find the one thats matching. I downloaded the third one from the list in this link - http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false but this driver is not being updated. Windows says that I've the latest driver.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta I've added the Realtek driver link

Comment: I tried to your link. But windows is saying `best driver for your device is already installed`.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta expend the zip, use Device manager and point to the INF file inside the extracted folder manually, don't let Windows search for a driver!